# Why git alias with push does not work?

Tags: git

Please, observe these Git commands:

```
C:\DeploymentSmokeTests [master ↑1]> git lg -n 2
* bd2e150 |  (HEAD -> master) Support Sql Server 2012. Limit the number of tested namespaces. (19 minutes ago) [Mark Kharitonov]
* 2d57b65 |  (origin/master) Merged PR 538: Implement the Schedule Jobs deployment test (36 minutes ago) [Kharitonov, Mark]
C:\DeploymentSmokeTests [master ↑1]> git config alias.shelve
!git branch shelve_$1;git checkout shelve_$1;git push -u origin shelve_$1
C:\DeploymentSmokeTests [master ↑1]> git shelve pbi405783
Switched to branch 'shelve_pbi405783'
error: src refspec pbi405783 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/DFDevOps/_git/DFDeploymentSmokeTests'
C:\Dayforce\DevOps\DFDeploymentSmokeTests [shelve_pbi405783]> git lg -n 2
* bd2e150 |  (HEAD -> shelve_pbi405783, master) Support Sql Server 2012. Limit the number of tested namespaces. (19 minutes ago) [Mark Kharitonov]
* 2d57b65 |  (origin/master) Merged PR 538: Implement the Schedule Jobs deployment test (37 minutes ago) [Kharitonov, Mark]
C:\DeploymentSmokeTests [shelve_pbi405783]>
```

Explanation:

- I have one commit to push to the server
- I have an alias called **shelve** which creates a branch, checks it out and pushes with tracking
- However, trying to use the alias I get an error, which I do not understand. For some reason it refuses to push.

Note, that running **push** separately works fine:

```
C:\DeploymentSmokeTests [shelve_pbi405783]> git push -u origin shelve_pbi405783
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 2.58 KiB | 2.58 MiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects... (9/9) (4 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (23 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (59 ms)
To http://tdc1tfsapp01:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/DFDevOps/_git/DFDeploymentSmokeTests
 * [new branch]      shelve_pbi405783 -> shelve_pbi405783
Branch 'shelve_pbi405783' set up to track remote branch 'shelve_pbi405783' from 'origin'.
C:\DeploymentSmokeTests [shelve_pbi405783 ≡]>
```

Comment: `error: src refspec pbi405783 does not match any.` It seems 'pbi405783' is not a valid refspec.

Comment: @gzh, but the alias isn't supposed to push `pbi405783`. It's supposed to push _`shelve_pbi405783`_. Why is the `shelve_` prefix not being seen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an argument to an alias, Git puts that argument after the alias's expansion.

This holds even if you use `$number` in the expansion.  Thus, the expansion text:

```
!git branch shelve_$1;git checkout shelve_$1;git push -u origin shelve_$1
```

when invoked becomes:

```
git branch shelve_pbi405783;
git checkout shelve_$pbi405783;
git push -u origin shelve_pbi405783 pbi405783
```

(I have broken this out into three separate lines for display and discussion purposes—internally it's all one big line).

The first and second commands are and do what you want.

The third command says to push *two* references, with the `-u` option set, to remote `origin`.  The first reference is `shelve_pbi405783`, which is what you want; the second reference is `pbi405783`.

Git successfully pushes `shelve_pbi405783` and sets its upstream to `origin/shelve_pbi405783`, but fails to push `pbi405783` as it does not exist.  So it prints that error message and stops, after doing what you want.

You could simply ignore the error, but it would be better to avoid it.  To avoid it you must write a shell command that accepts and disposes of the extra argument.  The usual method is to write a *shell function*:

```
'!f() { ...; } f'
```

The shell function itself then receives the parameters, and if it contains literal `$number` strings, those expand the appropriate parameter.  (So now it does not matter whether *Git* expands `$1`.)

Comment: Is the `'!f() { ...; } f'` syntax shell specific? I.e. is it bash? Because I am using PowerShell on windows.

Comment: Actually, I have a simpler solution - just add the echo command at the end, so the alias becomes `!git branch shelve_$1;git checkout shelve_$1;git push -u origin shelve_$1;echo`

Comment: Yes, that's POSIX-shell (bash/sh) for "define a function" then "call the function". Your "echo" trick will work too, it's just annoying to have it print something pointless :-)